# Java Bean programming, How to properly convert a parameter call to Expression Language

Tags: java, jsp, expression

So I have two parameters in my JSP page, but I want to convert them to Expression Language.

These are my parameters:

```
   <jsp:useBean id="tictactoe" class="bean.TicTacToe" scope="session"/>




    <jsp:setProperty name="tictactoe" property="reset" value= '<%=         request.getParameter("reset")%>' />





        <jsp:setProperty name="tictactoe" property="location1" value='<%=     .getParameter("location")%>'  />
```

I tried to just use this

```
 <jsp:setProperty name="tictactoe" property="location1" value="location")%>'  />
```

but I received a Number Format Exception.

I tried using this: ${para.loation1} in place of the JSP expression, but I received a malformed exception.

How can I convert my two JSP parameter request to Expression Language?

I'm at a lost.

I think I should use this, but haven't tried because I want to be sure I know what I am doing:

```
${tictactoe.reset.para.reset}
```

And for the other one,

```
${tictactoe.location1.para.location}
```

Will these work?

Comment: `${para.loation1}` or `${param.location}` ? which one you tried?

Comment: I tried the first one, and it didn't work. Was I supposed to try the second one?

Comment: Just tried them both, and both gave me a Number Format Exception.

Comment: Really, just forget entirely about jsp:useBean, jsp:setProperty, and scriptlets. These are terrible idea from a long long time ago. That kind of thing should be done by a controller written in Java (a servlet, for example). A JSP is a view used to generate HTML using the model prepared by the controller. And request parameters should not go to a bean stored in the session.

Comment: I figured it out my problem. Although I appreciate your recommendation, I have to use Expression Language and Java Beans. It's part of my assignment. I'll keep your concerns in mind for future products, however. Thanks!

Comment: jsp:useBean is not part of EL. jsp:setProperty is not part of EL. scriptlets are not part of EL. So you're using things that you shouldn't use.

Comment: @JB Nizet, thanks. I fixed the problem, however.